# How to automatically remove from SBT snapshot dependencies during release?

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, release

Is it possible to exchange snapshot dependency during release with its released version?
For example, I have such dependecy:

`libraryDependencies += "com.company" %% "del" % "10.0.12-SNAPSHOT"`

During release I'd like such dependency become

`libraryDependencies += "com.company" %% "del" % "10.0.12"`

Or interrupt release. Ideally if it is some sbt plugin with task, which could be triggered in Jenkins pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not depending on the snapshots at all. You can always depend on the last released versions of an artifact.

The `sbt-release` plugin should have the checks for depending on `-SNAPSHOTS` during the release [in place](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release#release-process) by default.

Comment: I agree with you, but currently I cannot be independ from snapshots... SBT releasechecks, but cannot upgrade such artifact. I need something as in Maven `mvn versions:use-releases`

Answer (score 0):

Script to clean, assembly and update snapshots.
When you release maintain a separate copy(remove snapshots) of version.sbt file on your build server.

```
import _root_.sbtrelease.ReleasePlugin.autoImport.{ReleaseStep, _}
import _root_.sbtrelease.ReleaseStateTransformations._

conflictManager in ThisBuild := sbt.ConflictManager.latestRevision

releaseProcess := Seq(
  ReleaseStep(releaseStepTaskAggregated(clean in *YourService*)),
  checkSnapshotDependencies,
  inquireVersions,
  setReleaseVersion,
  ReleaseStep(releaseStepTaskAggregated(assembly in *YourService*)),
  setNextVersion
)
```